# Implementing the offset function in Excel to calculate simple stats (Formula)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset

I have a massive amount of data which I would like to calculate some simple statistics (sum, mean, max). The data is grouped in columns and what I would like to do is calculate these statistics for the data in groups of sixteen columns. It is possible to manually select the columns to process but given the massive amount of data (365 columns x 601552 rows), I'm very likely to make mistakes. What I've been trying to figure out is how to get Excel to displace the cells selected each time the calculation is done. I know this entails the use of offset function but I can't figure out how to make it work. Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: 
Essentially the data looks as follows:

```
LAT   LONG       1      2      3       4    …    365
-40  -20     10.50   0.00   1.70    0.00    …   0.00
-40  -19.9   19.00   5.00   0.00    0.00    …   9.30
-40  -19.8    0.00   0.00   0.00    5.60    …   0.00
-40  -19.7   12.00   3.40   0.00    0.00    …   0.00
  …      …       …      …      …       …    …      …
 40   55      0.00   0.00   7.60    7.00    …   0.00
```

It is basically 365 days worth of rainfall for a large group of coordinates. What I want to do is collate basic stats (sum, mean and maximum rainfall) for each coordinate in 16-day aggregates (which comes to 22 full 16 day aggregates plus one with 13 or 14 days depending on whether it is a leap year). The formula I'm using right now is =SUM(OFFSET(C2,,,1,16)) which works fine for the first column (reference cell C2) but I want to copy this across the entire sheet. I think there is a way to get it to increment the reference cell by 16 each time but I can't seem to figure that out.

Comment: See EDIT. (I'm basically looking for a formula atm though I figure this could equally be done via a script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept of what you might be after. I've set it up to calculate statistics on a four-day cycle, but you should be able to extend it to a 16-day cycle:

[image]

- I copied the "labels" (LAT/LONG values) to duplicate the index.
- The formula in cell D17 is

  ```
  =IF(MOD(COLUMN()-2,4)=0,AVERAGE(OFFSET(D17,-15,-3,1,4)),
   IF(MOD(COLUMN()-2,4)=3,MEDIAN(OFFSET(D17,-15,-2,1,4)),
   IF(MOD(COLUMN()-2,4)=2,MAX(OFFSET(D17,-15,-1,1,4)),"")))
  ```

  where the condition is meant to only show a specific statistics based on the column you're in. The syntax `OFFSET(<ref>,<rows>,<cols>,<height>,<width>)` selects a range (`<rows>`,`<cols>`) from `<ref>` with a height of `<height>` and width `<width>`. So, for cell D17, `OFFSET(D17,-15,-3,1,4)` selects the 1x4 range with a top-left corner in C2.
- You can use the same formula to obtain the column labels `MAX`, `MEDIAN`, `AVG`, ...